# Using datediff in MySQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, datediff

This is my SQL statement that works using datediff:

```
SELECT SUM(b134_nettpay) AS Total, b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
FROM  B134HREC 
WHERE datediff (dd, '2006-05-05', getdate()) > 90
GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
ORDER BY b134_recdate DESC, b134_rmcid
```

I need to Replace the Hardcoded date '2006-05-05' with MAX(b134_recdate) like so:

```
SELECT SUM(b134_nettpay) AS Total, b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
FROM  B134HREC 
where datediff (dd, MAX(b134_recdate), getdate()) > 90
GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
ORDER BY b134_recdate DESC, b134_rmcid
```

But i get this Error message:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Any idea how to fix my SQL Statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(b134_nettpay) AS Total, b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
FROM  B134HRE 
where datediff (dd, 
      (select MAX(b134_recdate) from B134HRE)
      , getdate()) > 90
GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
ORDER BY b134_recdate DESC, b134_rmcid
```

Comment: This addresses the "or a select list" as suggested by the error message

Comment: As it stands the query cannot take advantage of any index that might be on b134_recdate (except for the max). If it were "where B134_rec_date > DateAdd(dd, getDate(), 90)" it would use an index, if it existed. NB: Not sure if dateadd syntax is correct, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving this:

`datediff (dd, MAX(b134_recdate), getdate()) > 90`

to a HAVING clause?

The sql statement would be:

`SELECT SUM(b134_nettpay) AS Total, b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
FROM  B134HRE 
GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
ORDER BY b134_recdate DESC, b134_rmcid
HAVING datediff (dd, MAX(b134_recdate), getdate()) > 90`

Comment: Tried this yes. Having datediff (dd, MAX(b134_recdate), getdate()) > 90.........then i get the error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' "

Comment: "where" limits the rows that are grouped, "having" limits which groups are returned. that will not work exactly the same

Comment: Putting recdate in "having" means you can't group by it.

Comment: funny, it should work... how was the entire statement then? Was the having the last clause?

Answer (score 0):

This code is for sql server

I'm not sure if the MAX sould be for the entire table:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate  datetime
SELECT @MaxDate=MAX(b134_recdate) FROM B134HRE
/* if you don't want time you need to trim it from @maxDate*/

    SELECT
        SUM(b134_nettpay) AS Total, b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
        FROM  B134HRE 
        where datediff (dd, @MaxDate, getdate()) > 90
        GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
        ORDER BY b134_recdate DESC, b134_rmcid
```

or per each group:

```
SELECT
    SUM(b.b134_nettpay) AS Total, b.b134_rmcid, b.b134_recdate 
    FROM  B134HRE   b
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        b134_rmcid, b134_recdate , MAX(b134_recdate) AS MaxDate
                        FROM B134HRE
                        GROUP BY b134_rmcid, b134_recdate 
                   ) dt ON b.b134_rmcid=dt.b134_rmcid AND b.b134_recdate=dt.b134_recdate
    where datediff (dd, dt.MaxDate, getdate()) > 90
    GROUP BY b.b134_rmcid, b.b134_recdate 
    ORDER BY b.b134_recdate DESC, b.b134_rmcid
```

but you could give these a try